# Start A Process With Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, parameters, process

I'm Using Process.Start from my website to open a windows form application I made in c#.

I want send to the application my username.

So how can I do that?

Comment: If you are using `Process.Start()` from a website, it will open that application on your *server*. Is that really what you want?

Comment: It's a school project, I know it shouldn't be like this but that's what their asking us to do for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Process.Start("MyExe.exe", "arguments");
```

Comment: And how do I access the username on my applications?

Comment: This won't work, because there will be no file called `MyExe.exe"username"`.

Comment: Just use `string myUsername = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1].ToString();` which will give you exaxtly what you put in as a parameter above.

Comment: @svick, I corrected it now "MyExe.exe" + " \"" + username + "\"" will compile to MyExe.exe "username" exactly. You can see that I put in escaped \" characters to enclose parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the escaping at first. But it still won't work this way, you have to put the command-line arguments as a separate argument to `Process.Start()`. Also, `Path.Combine()` doesn't do anything in your code.

Comment: @Mercurial1278 Great work! Instead of what you did I simply did : process.StartInfo.Arguments. but used your Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]

Answer (score 16):

You can do this by assigning arguments in start info, e.g.:

```
var process = new Process
      {
          StartInfo =
              {
                  FileName = processName,
                  Arguments = "-username=Alice"
              }
      };
process.Start();
```

If your process fails to start you might want to check permissions, as far as I am aware code running on IIS is not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 8):

`Process.Start()` has several overloads, [one of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) is for specifying the command-line arguments along with the path to the executable.

For example:

```
Process.Start("app.exe", "parameter(s)");
```

Comment: Ok but again, how do I access the parameter from my applications?

Comment: @Or, the same way Mercurial suggested, using [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, should be working

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SSHPit
{

public partial class MainForm : Form
{       
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
    
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);


    public MainForm()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "L:\\Program Files\\putty\\putty.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-load \"mysession\" -ssh 127.0.0.1";
        p.Start();
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        while (p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
           Thread.Sleep(100); 
           p.Refresh();
        }
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
    }
}
}
```