# C# assigning value to variable says it cannot find the file?

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I have what should be a very simple method which runs a batch file. The method is this:

```
private  string _binnPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Binn";

public void DumpFileSystem(string snapshotFolder)
{
    var cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(_binnPath);

    var snapshotOutput = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, snapshotFolder);
    snapshotOutput = Path.Combine(snapshotOutput, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks + "-files.txt");

    var batCommand = _binnPath + "\\DumpFileSystem.bat";
    string batFilename = batCommand + " " + snapshotOutput;

    using (var process = Process.Start(batFilename))
    {
        process?.WaitForExit();
    }

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(cwd);
}
```

The batch file is this:

```
dir /s c:\ >  %1
```

on the line `var batCommand = _binnPath + "\\DumpFileSystem.bat";` I receive this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

which makes no sense at all as I am only assigning a variable.
All I want to do is run the batch file with the snapshotOutput variable.
This shouldn't be that difficult.

**Questions**

1. Any ideas how to get the batch file run? and
2. Why does the error get thrown when the setting of the variable should not even be looking for a file?

Comment: put a breakpoint on Process.Start(batFilename), debug and stop there, see the value of batFilename and check if the file is at the location you're expecting it to be. Changes are that the file is not in the %APPROOT%/bin/debug/Binn folder

Comment: I think it may because you try to pass arguments into what should be a path.

Comment: Why do you call SetCurrentDirectory function? Did you try commenting out that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove these code

```
string batFilename = batCommand + " " + snapshotOutput;
```

you have to change process start

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(batCommand , snapshotOutput))
```

Comment: Straight to the point. Even like it better than my own answer.

Comment: Ok this worked - but why? the line that you said I should remove was only a variable assignment. I hadn't got to the running of the process when the error occurred.

Comment: @Toxantron said correctly: "This is an optical illusion in Visual Studio often caused by older files or code optimization." The error is in "Process.Start" but visual studio throw exception in the upper row. I suggest to emit a Console.Writeline on the row before Process.Start, it will be executed in both version...

Answer (score 1):

1. You should only pass in the path to the batch and the arguments explicitly. Otherwise windows tries to incorporate the arguments into the path that does not exist.
2. This is an optical illusion in Visual Studio often caused by older files or code optimization.

Please look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5766669/6082960