# C#: How can I open a process, wait until the program in the process loads completely, and then use a new process to execute commands?

Tags: c#

With C#, I need to open a program, wait until that program is completely loaded, and then I want to run the cmd.exe to run additional commands to operate the original instance of the program.

I am trying to get a specific program called GerbView to behave in a certain way. This program is used to view Gerber files, files that PCB manufacturers use to etch PCBs. This program can internally load Gerber files with it's own Open command. However, my program is meant to process some of these Gerber files and then use GerbView to load up these processed Gerber files. The only way I will be able to accomplish this task is via the command line interface. The command that can open a Gerber file is **gerbview {filename}**.

I know that the Process class can do this easily with the FileName and Arguments properties but I need to add more files to the same instance. The command to do this is **gerbview /add {filename}**.

This last command will start the program and if an instance is already open, it will just add an additional file to view. Now this is where I have my problem. Until I came with my final solution (see below), my program kept opening multiple instances (despite using the **/add** argument), probably because the program was not ready for input while the rest of **/add** arguments were executing. Only when I added a 1 second delay did the code run correctly. However, when I was showing someone over Microsoft Teams, the old behavior came back until I increased the delay (I'm assuming the Teams broadcast gave cause for the need of a larger delay). The following is my current solution (the program is part of a windows form):

```cs
Process gerbView;
Process cmd;
bool gerbViewActive;

// The is the windows form constructor
public WindowsFormGUI()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gerbViewActive = false;
}

private void buttonRunProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog loadFiles = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Multiselect = true,
        InitialDirectory = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName
    };

    if (loadFiles.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (!gerbViewActive)
        {
            gerbView = new Process();
            gerbView.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            gerbView.Exited += new EventHandler(GerbView_Exited);
            gerbView.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Software Companions\GerbView\gerbview.exe";
            gerbView.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            gerbView.Start();
            gerbViewActive = true;
        }
        
        // wait until GerbView loads before running the cmd process.
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        
        string[] files = loadFiles.FileNames;
        cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Software Companions\GerbView\";
        cmd.Start();
        using (StreamWriter cmdInput = cmd.StandardInput)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
            {
                cmdInput.WriteLine("gerbview.exe /add " + files[index]);
            }
        }
        cmd.Close();
    }
}

private void GerbView_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gerbViewActive = false;
    gerbView.Close();
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome and congrats on your first post! I like the details you provided but I can see why someone would downvote you - you need more focus with your question. Also, you could show a bit more troubleshooting on your side. I wish you the best with your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the command line tool you are executing, must be trying to locate the existing process and communicate with it. I would skip running `cmd.exe`, and just run each `gerbview.exe /add` process yourself. Then you can `.WaitForExit()` to ensure that each process has finished before starting another one. However that may not be sufficient.

Next, you'll need to `.WaitForInputIdle()` on the main UI process to block until the main thread has cleared it's win32 event queue. This is likely to be a necessary condition for their file open command line to successfully communicate with it.

To be explicit, the minimum set of steps you'll want is;

- start the main process "gerbview.exe", then loop over files;

  - main process .WaitForInputIdle
  - start "gerbview.exe" with arguments $"/add "{filename}""
  - .WaitForExit of this "gerbview.exe" process

Since you are starting the same viewer executable as the main UI and to open each file, it's likely to be a "windows subsystem" executable rather than a console executable. cmd.exe would be starting the process, but not blocking until it has exited. The only way to be certain it has quit, is to start the process yourself.

You could also try posting or sending some noop window message to the viewer process's window handle, to ensure that .WaitForInputIdle has some new input to wait for.

None of this will guarantee that this process will work. That depends entirely on how this 3rd party application is written.

Comment: "*Next, you'll need to .WaitForInputIdle()*"  and "*This is likely to be a necessary condition*" - but this is still an assumption and might not be the case. If this doesn't work, the problem becomes a lot harder

Comment: My program snippet shows that I am opening a GerbView process to activate the program because without the first instance I cannot add multiple files to the viewer automatically. I open the cmd.exe process so I can automatically run the /add argument. I cannot run the /add manually as it defeats the purpose for automation. If I use the .WaitForExit() method, it will lock the program waiting until GerbView exits which I do not want. I tried just now to use .WaitForInputIdle() and it did not wait until GerbView loaded completely. As the code snippet stands, it works as I expect but I was hoping

Comment: for an option that would allow a dynamic wait instead of a Thread.Sleep() line of code.

Comment: " I open the cmd.exe process so I can automatically run the /add argument" Just pass the parameters yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766574/start-a-process-with-parameters. Then you can wait for that process to exit, not the cmd or main view process. Otherwise you might .WaitForInputIdle on the main view process too early.